# Why doesn't my Android 7.0 smartphone have Ambient display?

Tags: notifications, 7.0-nougat

I'm trying to figure out why my Android smartphone isn't showing notification on the lock screen when I receive a new Skype message. After some researchings, I found that it seems to have something to do with a featured called "Ambient display".

As [this article](https://www.technologyhint.com/enable-ambient-display-android/) explains, Ambient display is a feature introduced on Lollipop (Android 5.0) and above, and it wakes the device and light up the display for a few seconds when new notifications arrive.

My Android version is Nougat (Android 7.0) so it is supposed to have Ambient display. But after I followed the instruction of that article and went to Setting > Display, I cannot find any option called Ambient display.

Why doesn't my Android 7.0 smartphone have Ambient display?

== Edit ==

My device is CAT S41.

Comment: I am not familiar with this device specifically, but it is not unheard of for OEMs to disable certain Android features... Ambient display being a common one, often due to the type of display panel or issues with battery consumption on some devices. The only thing you can really do is complain to the OEM/Vendor, although it is unlikely, they could enable it in a future update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your device doesn't have it as per the manual you can download from [here](https://catphones.com/en_gb/support/s41-support)
- But it does the Ambient  light sensor as mentioned [here](https://www.androidauthority.com/cat-s41-review-815500/)

Reasons for not enabling it are best known to OEM and you can ascertain from them and also request for inclusion in future updates (unlikely they would heed your request)

**Edit**

As suspected it doesn't support. [Chat](https://www.catphones.com/en_gb/support.html) screenshots

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. "Not being mentioned in the manual" doesn't necessarily mean "Not having it". It's likely that it does not have it, but we need to wait for the OEM's response before making the conclusion. Besides, "Ambient light sensor" does not seem to be related to "Ambient display".

Comment: Thanks for reaching them out. They also responded to my email and said Ambient display does not come on their Android nougat phone as standard. So it is confirmed that CAT S41 does not have the feature.

Comment: Okay. I just deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question what you need to do is in the settings go to "My device" press "Lock screen" then "Screen lock" as if you are going to change your password/code etc. then highlight "Show all content" that will make all notifications appear when you turn on your phone even if you don't unlock it.

Comment: Thanks. I had already enabled it. But the issue remains.